# CakePHP Facebook Plugin does not displays the logout button in FIrefox

Tags: php, facebook, cakephp, sdk

I'm working with webtechnick CakePHP Facebook Plugin, I finally managed to make it work (I can use the like/recommend buttons - I can login via facebook, etc) except for the logout button in Firefox v3.6 and IE that is not working. I think there is a problem because in Chrome the logout button get display and the PHP code works fine also. I have this code into a *.cpt view file:

```
if($facebook_user){
    echo $this->Facebook->logout();
    echo debug($facebook_user);
} else {
    echo $this->Facebook->login(array());
}
```

In Chrome after I click on the login button, the $facebook_user is true and the logout button get display as well as the debug(), therefor PHP is fine but in Firefox or IE the logout button gets hide almost instantly.

I'm following the video tutorial and the problem seems to be in the minute 19~
http://tv.cakephp.org/video/webtechnick/2011/01/12/nick_baker_--_facebook_integration_with_cakephp

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by enabling in Firefox's options on Privacy the "Accept third-party cookies"